# extjs C# execute js from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs, webforms

How I can execute JavaScript code from codebehind?

Executing in `aspx.cs` via:

```
 X.Js.AddScript("alert('Hello World!')");
```

is not working.

Comment: With ScripManager `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "testJS", "alert('test')", true);`

Comment: Add your complete code, and show what's going wrong

Comment: @AlexandreN. This is my complete code. Its in a button click event. By clicking the button I can see that this line is called but its not working. I just want to execute Js code in code behind on button click so I can refresh a page calling js function in parent page

Comment: Add the full HTML and CS code, only that you informed nobody will be able to help you